# I am trying to delete a word from a file in C

Tags: c

I wrote a program to remove a certain word (taken as user input) from a file. I read the word, opened the file from which I wanted to delete the word, read each line in the file and split it into words, and compared each word with my keyword. If they are not a match, I printed them into a temporary file.

But when I open the temp file, the entire text has been copied. Can somebody help me????

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
{
int i;
FILE *fp1,*fp2;
char key[1000],a[1000],temp[1000];

printf("\nEnter the word to be deleted from file : ");
scanf("%s",key);

fp1 = fopen("a.txt","r");
fp2 = fopen("b.txt","w");

while(fgets(a,1000,fp1))
{
    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';++i)

        if(a[i]==' ')
            break;
        else            
            temp[i]=a[i];
    temp[i]='\0';
    if(strcmp(temp,key)!=0)
    {
        fputs(temp,fp2);
    }

    bzero(a,1000);
}

fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);

printf("\n\n");

/*remove("a.txt");
rename("b.txt","a.txt");*/

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: OK, congratulations, but that's a slow way to do it. Was there a question there?

Comment: write to a tmp file then move it.

Comment: im sorry, i edited it with a question

Comment: i did, bt it dint work

Comment: Is this about learning C? Or solving the problem? Because this can be done with a couple of characters of sed.

Comment: Whoa, `main` without return type ... *oldschool*! :)

Comment: @AdamBurry its about solving the problem, in a way i can understand...

Comment: @bitmask i never understood why should one use main with return type??? is there any specific reason?????

Comment: @HariKMalayath: Letting a type (any type in any declaration or definition) default to int is a very old artefact from the early days of C before it was standardised. Incidentally, it indicates a lack of proper warning flags or the ignoring of the resulting warnings.

Comment: @bitmask oh i c :) thnks.....

Comment: I don't see how it's possible that your function is copying the entire text to `b.txt` in most cases since it won't even look at any words in `a.txt` beyond the first space it finds.

Comment: @mbratch why do you say that????

Comment: When I ran this function, it actually will work to an extent. As I mentioned, it ignores any words in `a.txt` that exist past the first space on each line. But the output is indeed all of the words that don't match the word I gave it and it doesn't output the matching word. Although, the output is just all of the non-matching words mashed together with no spaces or line breaks. Could you please check it again and reformulate the question? It's a little unclear what you really want the output to look like and what an input file is supposed to look like.

Comment: @HariKMalayath I misstated it a bit, I meant "for each line" (not the entire file) it only looks at the first word. This is for two reasons. Firstly, each time through the loop reads the next line in the file, and within that loop, there's an initial `for` loop which breaks as soon as the first space is hit. After the space is discovered, the captured words is processed, and the main loop goes around again and reads a new line. Secondly, I ran the code and it behaves exactly as I just described. :)

Comment: **must** it be a complete isolated word (separated by whitespace or punctuation) ? Or can it be any substring, and should,for instance  with `key="con"` "continue" be replaced by "tinue"

Comment: @wildplasser yes it should be an isolated word, not a substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another solution. It has some of the same problems mentioned above, for example the boundaries of a word do not really match English grammar. It also has an inefficiency of doing more copies than is strictly necessary in some cases.

However, I prefer this version over yours because it abstracts the word removal task rather than doing it inline with the rest of the code. Plus it works better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void remove_str2(char* buffer, char* find, int lfind) {
  char* paste = strstr(buffer, find);
  if (!paste) { return; }
  char* start = paste + lfind;

  while (1) {
    char* end = strstr(start, find);
    if (!end) {
      end = start + strlen(start) + 1;
    }
    memmove(paste, start, end - start);

    paste += end - start;
    start = strstr(end, find);
    if (!start) { return; }
    start += lfind;
  }
}

void remove_str(char* buffer, char* find, int lfind) {
  char* p = strstr(buffer, find);
  if (p) {
    remove_str(p + lfind, find, lfind);
    // shift everything left
    do { *p = *(p + lfind); } while (*(++p));
  }
}

int main() {
  FILE *fp1, *fp2;
  char key[1000], a[1000];

  // require key to be preceeded by a space
  key[0] = ' ';

  printf("\nEnter the word to be deleted from file : ");
  scanf("%s", &key[1]);

  fp1 = fopen("a.txt","r");
  fp2 = fopen("b.txt","w");

  while (fgets(a, 1000, fp1)) {
    remove_str(a, key, strlen(key));
    fputs(a, fp2);
  }

  fclose(fp1);
  fclose(fp2);

  printf("\n\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain the removal processs?

Comment: @HariKMalayath, strstr (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr) does a substring search for key in your input buffer. If it is not found, then return because there is no work to do. If it is found it skips over it and searches the rest of the buffer for key, and so on recursively. As the stack unwinds it copies all the characters back over the keys to be removed. As I said, there is an inefficiency there, but it is simple to understand and code.

Comment: For comparison purposes, I added a version of remove_str that minimizes the copying.

Comment: It does not respect the word-boundaries. (see my comment on the OQ)

Comment: @wildplasser, the question does not specify start and end constraints for word boundaries other than those used in the broken sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that as soon as you find a space you process the word, but you don't finish processing the remainder of the line. After the fputs, you go to the top of the loop and read another line. When I compile and run your snippet, it indeed ouputs the first word of each line as long as it's not the selected word.

Also when outputting your words, you don't output any space between them and there is no carriage return at the end of lines. Thus all non-matching words are output back-to-back on one line.

There's a few more issues that the following snippet fixes (there's some remaining problems that I didn't solve-- for example, the last non-matching word on a line is not output if there is no trailing space on the line. You can solve this by looking for '\0' as well as space. I didn't do it because it requires changing the loop structure to not exit when '\0' is seen so you get a chance to test for it):

```
    while(fgets(a,1000,fp1))
    {
        int j = 0;
        for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';++i)

            if((a[i]==' '){
             temp[j++]='\0';
             if(strcmp(temp,key)!=0) {
                fprintf (fp2, "%s ", temp);
                }
             j = 0;
            }
           else
             temp[j++]=a[i];
          fprintf (fp2, "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to compile it and it works almost fine except it doesn't insert spaces in output file ;)

```
if(strcmp(temp,key)!=0)
{
    temp[i++] = ' ';
    temp[i] = '\0';
    fputs(temp,fp2);
}
```

Also, its' very sensitive code. It doesn't work if I have a line of words. And it shouldn't work if your test file has a spaces before word and your keyword doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations,

```
main()
{
    //you will need input index, output index
    int in, on; //in: input index, on: output index
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    char key[1000],iray[1000],oray[1000];
    char* here; //clarifies the comparison

    printf("\nEnter the word to be deleted from file : ");
    scanf("%s",key);
    printf("key: %s",key); fflush(stdout);

    if(!(fp1 = fopen("a.txt","r"))) { printf("open error\n"); exit(1); }
    if(!(fp2 = fopen("b.txt","w"))) { printf("open error\n"); exit(2); }

    while(fgets(iray,sizeof(iray),fp1))
    {
        printf("line: %s",iray); fflush(stdout);
        for(in=on=0; iray[in]; ++in) //'\0' = 0 = false //please indent
        {   //please use braces
            //printf("%d: %c\n",in,iray[in]); fflush(stdout);
            if(iray[in]==' ')
            {
                oray[on++] = iray[in];
                continue; //break gets you out of loop
            }
            here = &(iray[in]);
            //printf("here: %s\n",here); fflush(stdout);
            if( !strcmp(here,key) ) //have word?
            {
                in+=strlen(key); //skip word
                continue;
            }
            oray[on++] = iray[in];
        }
        oray[on] = '\0';
        printf("line: %s",oray); fflush(stdout);
        fputs(oray,fp2);
        iray[0]=0; //bzero(iray,1000);
        oray[0]=0; //bzero(oray,1000);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: a complete solution: 
this is how your loop should look like:

```
while(fgets(a,1000,fp1))
{
  int j=0;
  for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';++i)
  {
    if(a[i]==' ')
    {
       temp[j]=0;
       if(strcmp(temp,key)!=0)
       {
          fputs(temp,fp2);
       }
       j=0;
       //this should be after fputs if you want to remove the space after obsolete word. 
        fputs(" ",fp2);         
    }
    else            
       temp[j++]=a[i];          
  }
  //last word if there is no space after!
  if(strcmp(temp,key)!=0)
  {
    fputs(temp,fp2);
  }
  fputs("\n",fp2);
  a[0] = 0;
}
```

Comment: you should use isspace(x) instead x==' '